# Future tasks which are named and dynamically modifiable

Tags: java, spring

I have a use case where a user is able to submit choices(from a predefined list) for the 7 days of the week and I call a third party application which stores this data. The user also has the ability to update the choices and what I am looking for, is to store all of the choices in memory and keep updating them whenever he changes his choices, so that I can call the third party application once after a fixed delay.

Now, the requirement I am looking at is,

- be able to store the data in memory and not use any persistent storage(which sounds risky, but persistence is a future roadmap).
- Run a "named" scheduler if you will, which can be accessed , updated with new choice and time reset.

I have a spring 3 application and HttpSessionListener, SessionBindingListener implementations do not work for me since session time out is fairly long in the application.

Thanks for looking and would be happy to explain in case anything is unclear. Any help is greatly appreciated!!